# gitlab-ci.yml: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, shell, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I am implementing Auto Build in my Gitlab project. For that I am using `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with multi-line YAML blocks containing shell commands, the code is as follows:

```
if [ "${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}" != "nadirabbas" ]
    then
        echo "Building"
        if [ ! -d "dist" ]; then mkdir dist; fi
        if [ ! -f "dist/index.html" ]; then touch dist/index.html; fi
fi
```

I have tried many solutions such as putting a `;` after the if statement, also after the `fi` keyword, but nothing seems to work, My job log returns the following syntax error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

I have tried to google it, but other solutions don't seem to work. The shell my runner is using is `bash`.

Comment: The easiest solution would probably to put this script in its own file, and have gitlab-ci call it.

Comment: @Mureinik, can you tell me how can I do that?

Comment: I put the details in an answer, comments don't really have the space for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, the easiest approach would probably to have the script in its own file (make sure it's executable!), and then just call it from gitlab ci.

E.g., you can have a `build.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}" != "nadirabbas" ]
    then
        echo "Building"
        if [ ! -d "dist" ]; then mkdir dist; fi
        if [ ! -f "dist/index.html" ]; then touch dist/index.html; fi
fi
```

And then call it from the yml:

```
some_task:
  image: ubuntu:18.04
  script:
  - ./build.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `.gitlab-ci.yml`  doesn't really allow for multi-line scripts (which is more a restriction of YAML than of gitlab).

So if you don't want to use a script (as suggested by @Mureinik), you could collapse everything into a single line:

```yaml
  script:
  - if [ "${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}" != "nadirabbas" ]; then echo "Building"; mkdir -p dist; touch -a dist/index.html; fi
```

(I also removed the inner `if`-conditions; as you can use flags to `mkdir` and `touch` to get approximately the same behaviour)

Comment: It does support if you start the line with |

Comment: It is totally garbage. It fails without any valid reason. I wasted 1 day, still I couldnt run a for loop. one for loop works fine, another not. sometimes it looks to me, it works totally random

Answer (score 1):

For me, using the `- |` (mind the space between the `-` and the `|`) syntax works for multi-line bash scripts:

```yaml
script:
  - |
    if [ "${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}" != "nadirabbas" ]
      then
        echo "Building"
        if [ ! -d "dist" ]; then mkdir dist; fi
        if [ ! -f "dist/index.html" ]; then touch dist/index.html; fi
    fi
```

Mind that the lines of the script have to start at the same level of indentation.

See also the official [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the issue wasn't in the multi-line, which is supported by GitLab now. The problem was running the bash logic in sh shell container `docker:dind` or `alpine` the fix is running the logic with bash:

```yaml
job-name:
  script:
    - apk update && apk add bash
    - |+
      bash -c '
        if [[ -n "$DOWNLOAD_FILE" ]]; then
          DOWNLOAD_LIST=($DOWNLOAD_FILE)
          for file in ${DOWNLOAD_LIST[@]}; do
            echo "downloading $file"
            wget -q $file
          done
        fi
      '
```